# Custom attribute not showing in advance search page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created custom attribute programmatically as show below code.

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group' => 'General',
    'input' => 'select',
    'type' => 'int',
    'label' => 'custom_attribute',
    'source' => 'Namespace_Module_Model_Source_Customattribute',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'searchable' => 0,
    'filterable' => 0,
    'comparable' => 0,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

In this above script I have set  `'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0` but now I have requirement that I need to enable to for advance search.

For that I created upgrade script and used this code to modify this attribute.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_attribute', 'is_visible_in_advanced_search', 1);
$installer->endSetup();
```

But it hasn't worked. Please suggest what should I do to enable it for advance search.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code it will update `is_visible_in_advanced_search` field as expected. Do you have options assigned to your attribute?

This is how attributes are collected in `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced`

```
public function getAttributes()
{
    /* @var $attributes Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection */
    $attributes = $this->getData('attributes');
    if (is_null($attributes)) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ->addHasOptionsFilter()
            ->addDisplayInAdvancedSearchFilter()
            ->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->setOrder('main_table.attribute_id', 'asc')
            ->load();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $attribute->setEntity($product->getResource());
        }
        $this->setData('attributes', $attributes);
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try run this sql query

> SELECT `main_table`.`entity_type_id`, `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`, `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`, `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`, `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`, `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`, `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`, `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`, `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.*, `ao`.`option_id`, IFNULL(al.value, main_table.frontend_label) AS `store_label` FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `ao` ON ao.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_label` AS `al` ON al.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND al.store_id = 1 WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = 4) AND ((main_table.frontend_input = 'select' AND ao.option_id > 0) OR (main_table.frontend_input <> 'select') OR (main_table.is_user_defined = 0)) AND (`additional_table`.`is_visible_in_advanced_search` = '1') GROUP BY `main_table`.`attribute_id` ORDER BY main_table.attribute_id ASC

usually because your attribute don't have any option value yet